# Java Regex to look for files in multiple directories

Tags: java, regex, file

I am trying to look for files with ".js", ".less", ".jsp", and ".png" files while also checking for them in many different directories for example *"/MyProject/public/someSecurePage.jsp", "/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage1/", "/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage2/", "/MyProject/public/less/page/SecuredPage1/"*, etc

I am using the `someString.macthes(regexString)`

Right now I have 2 separate regexes, but I am not sure they are correct:

File exts

```
.*?\\.(jsp|less|css|png|js)$
```

Directories/Files

**EDIT1:**

```
.*?\\.(/MyProject/public/someSecurePage.jsp|/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPag‌​e1/|/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage2/|/MyProject/public/less/page/SecuredPa‌​ge1/)
```

**EDIT1:**

Another issue I am looking at is that this does not seem to look at `/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage2/securedPage2.js` is not getting read correctly, my if statement is coming to false with this check.

My issue is that I am not actually sure that my files/ directories one is correct, because going through an if statement trying to match a directory, comes to false. I am new to using regular expressions

Comment: I don't think  the double forward slashes `//` are necessary, you should be able to just use a single slash. `.*?\\.(/MyProject/public/someSecurePage.jsp|/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage1/|/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage2/|/MyProject/public/less/page/SecuredPage1/)$` I could be wrong though.

Comment: I wasnt sure because I thought one slash was an escape character, that is kinda a reason I am asking

Comment: Only the backslash "\" is an escape character.

Comment: Okay I will try out the single forward slash

Comment: Also, you may not want to have the `$` at the end of your second regex, unless it is only searching the directories, without the file names attached. `$` means end of the string.

Comment: oh okay, that might actually be the issue then, let me test it

Comment: So far, no dice. It still overlooks my file in that directory

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer with a fully modified regex. See if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the full regex you want. If you only want to find files in "/MyProject/public/someSecurePage/", "/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPag‌e1/", "/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage2", and "/MyProject/public/less/page/SecuredPa‌​ge1/" with extensions "jsp", "less", "css", "png", and "js".

```
^.*(/MyProject/public/someSecurePage|/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPag‌ e1|/MyProject/public/js/page/SecuredPage2|/MyProject/public/less/page/SecuredPa‌​ge1)/.*\\.(jsp|less|css|png|js)$
```

`^.*` means match anything 0 or more times starting from the beginning (honestly you may not even need this part for it to work). `^` Means beginning, `$` means end.

`/.*\\.` means match forward slash anything dot. E.g. `/MyProject/public/less/page/SecuredPa‌​ge1/qwerty.` would be a match if we left out `(jsp|less|css|png|js)`

Comment: if you dont mind, would you be able to explain how the characters before the '( )' work?

Comment: Awesome. Sure, before which set of '()'?

Comment: both if you dont mind. from my understanding I think the first one matches any sequence, but I am not totally sure

Comment: No problem. Let me know if I need to explain it any better.